# Как заставить раскрыть ToggleBox если невалидны поля внутри него?

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

Есть redux форма и одно поле внутри

```
<form onSubmit={...}>
   <ToggleBox collapsed={...}> 
     <Field
            name="firstName"
            component="input"
            type="text"
            placeholder="First Name"
          />
   </ToggleBox> 

   <button type="submit"> 
</form>
```

Если поле firstName не заполнено, то форма невалидна, и надо раскрыть ToggleBox (свойство collapsed=false) чтобы невалидное поле подсветилось.

Как в redux-form правильно делается в таком случае?

Answer (score 0):

Лучше завернуть Field в компонент ErrorField такого содержания(meta.touched - показывает был ли инпут в фокусе, что бы ошибки сразу после рендера не показывались):

```js
import React from "react";

function ErrorField(props) {
const {input, placeholder, type, meta: {error, touched}} = props
const errorText = touched && error && <div style={{color: 'red'}}> {error}</div>   
return (
    <div>
        <label>{input.name}</label>
        <input {...input} type={type} placeholder={placeholder} />
        {errorText}
    </div>
);
}

export default ErrorField;
```

Тогда вы сможете его вызывать для валидации всех остальных форм. Ну и ваш основной компонент переделать:

```js
<Field
        name="firstName"
        component="ErrorField"
        type="text"
        placeholder="First Name"
      />
//....
const validate = ({firstName}) => {
  const errors = {};

  if(!firstName) errors.firstName= "Нужно ввести имя"; 
  else if (firstName.length < 8) errors.firstName= "Имя должно быть больше 8 символов"; 

  return errors;
}
//......
export default reduxForm({
  //подключаем форму form: "test",
  validate
})(ComponentName)
```

Comment: Т.е. должно быть как-то так ?
<ToggleBox collapsed={!(meta.touched && meta.error)}>

Comment: Немного напортачил в поле Field и validate, и meta.errors - это объект, и он всегда  true